# Serve Server Root instead of Subfolder when accessing my webserver through it's domain

Tags: linux, debian, apache-http-server, nextcloud

I have a apache 2.4.38 webserver, running on my Debian 10 Buster server. In my /var/www/html, I have a index.html file, and a folder "nextcloud", with a nextcloud instance installed. If I type the IP of my server into my browser, the index.html file shows(that's the behavior I want). However, if I type my domain name into my browser, only the domain, without adding /nextcloud to the URL, nextcloud loads. This is unwanted behavior. When simply typing in my domain name, without specifying a subfolder, I want my custom index.html to show. In /etc/apache2/sites-enabled, I have 3 files:

000-default.conf

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

nextcloud.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin MY_EMAIL_CENSORED
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/nextcloud/
     ServerName MY_DOMAIN_CENSORED

     Alias /nextcloud "/var/www/html/nextcloud/"

     <Directory /var/www/html/nextcloud/>
        Options +FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
          <IfModule mod_dav.c>
            Dav off
          </IfModule>
        SetEnv HOME /var/www/html/nextcloud
        SetEnv HTTP_HOME /var/www/html/nextcloud
     </Directory>

     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =MY_DOMAIN_CENSORED
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

nextcloud-le-ssl.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
     ServerAdmin MY_EMAIL_CENSORED
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/nextcloud/
     ServerName MY_DOMAIN_CENSORED

     Alias /nextcloud "/var/www/html/nextcloud/"

     <Directory /var/www/html/nextcloud/>
        Options +FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
          <IfModule mod_dav.c>
            Dav off
          </IfModule>
        SetEnv HOME /var/www/html/nextcloud
        SetEnv HTTP_HOME /var/www/html/nextcloud
     </Directory>

     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/MY_DOMAIN_CENSORED/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/MY_DOMAIN_CENSORED/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Thank You very much for your time, attention and help!

Simon

Answer (score 0):

Your domain name is present on both ports 80 and 443 as it should be. So when `MY_DOMAIN_CENSORED` loads it is referred to `/var/www/html/nextcloud/`. This is what it looks like in both 80 and 443:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/nextcloud/
ServerName MY_DOMAIN_CENSORED
```

Change `/var/www/html/nextcloud/` to `/var/www/html/` in both the 80 and 443 VirtualHost files.